# Use UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum and save to custom album

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

Can I use **UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum** and save to a custom album, say for example to "My App Videos" album?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is saved to Camera Roll Album as stated in the docs.

You can use the code in this tutorial which has a helper classes to easily save images to custom album

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/